# Colapsible panel within accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

http://jsfiddle.net/EGjVe/83/

I am trying to add a collapsible panel within a section of the JQUERY-UI-ACCORDION
I need the height of each panel to by dynamic based on the height of each content.

Trying autoheight true or false makes no difference or even fillspace and clearstyle true

Basically the outer accordion section height needs to be the height of the inner collapsible panel when open or closed.

Just to clarify after reading the reply below. The inner accordion work by clicking the link and expanding the corresponding panel. When this happens I need the outer panel to resize. and not always have a large height.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the according works in this manner. You can fill the parent element or take the largest content height but it won't change the height as you open / close sections. Maybe you could create your own click handler and use hide / show and add / removeClass to do what you want?